# How to fix authentication error code 10000 in cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflarestream

There is problem, i keep encountering  in  cloudflare. It says - **authentication error (code 10000)** while logging to my cloudflare dashbord.

don't know why that's happen,but

i searched for that problem on google,ask cloudflare help center, but did't get any response till now. I tried clearing catch, restart my device again, but still getting that error.

could any one please help me know, why i'm getting this **error** and  how could solve this **authentication error code 10000** because i'm unable  to logged into my cloudflare account, i ran website and manage all thing from their

Answer (score 0):

*You will need to assign the right permission to your user, that is trying to access cloudflare.*

Here is their Api permissions doc:
**https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/tokens/create/permissions/**