# Unable to update A record on CloudFlare using terraform

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

I am trying to create A record in my account. I am using the below mentioned code(changed the sensitive data):

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
      version = "4.20.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "cloudflare" {

  # Cloudflare API credentials configuration
  api_token = "YE9d0KcX97OspLySwYLC475Sx42DPlfBEU_3FjqU"
}

data "cloudflare_record" "www"{
  zone_id  = "1fa42c8d2132a9ddaf714f9e7c920711"
  hostname = "sidharthvijayakumar.fun"
  type = "A"
}
```

When I run terraform apply on this main.tf file I am getting a error:

`Error: error listing DNS records: Authentication error (10000) with data.cloudflare_record.www, │   on main.tf line 15, in data "cloudflare_record" "www": │   15: data "cloudflare_record" "www"{`

I have referred to this question [stackover flow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730051/how-to-fix-authentication-error-code-10000-in-cloudflare) but I am not able to figure out what is the exact permission which my api_token needs [Cloud flare document](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/api/reference/permissions/). Can someone help me ?

I tried to create a api_token with DNS read permission:

[image: API_TOKEN]

[image: API Token summary]

Even after adding this api_token I get the same error.

Comment: Is that your real token? Revoke it if so

Comment: no its changed so that I do not expose the sensitive data

Answer (score 0):

For read Cloudflare zone DNS records your token should have DNS:Read permission.

You can grant it for specific zone or for all zones in the account like shoved here:

[image: zone dns read]

Comment: I tried this and updated my question am still getting the same error

Comment: if so, then I have only one guess - the zone id is incorrect